# Conditional expectation involving Brownian Bridge

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

I have no ideas on this problem:

Let $(B_t, 0 \leq t \leq 1)$ be a standard Brownian motion in $1$ dimension. Let $Z^y_t = yt+ (B_t -tB_1)$. We call $\{Z^y_t\}_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$ a Brownian Bridge from $0$ to $y$. Let $W^y_0$ be the law of $(Z^y_t, 0 \leq t \leq 1)$ on $\mathcal{C} [0,1]$. We want to show that for any non-negative measurable function $F: \mathcal{C} [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$, if $f(y)= W^y_0 (F)$, then we have $$ \mathbb{E} [F(B) | B_1] =f(B_1) \quad \text{ a.s.} $$
Any ideas of how to approach this problem?

Comment: In the displayed equation, what is $B$?

Comment: $B$ should be the Brownian motion $(B_t)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notation: $W_0^y$ has to be applied on a Borel subset of $\mathcal C[0,1]$. What is $W_0^y(F)$?

Comment: Me too, I don't really understand :(

Comment: Is this problem from a textbook? In this case the notation is probably defined before.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the notation is not clearly defined. I might have to bring the book to ask some of my professors.